# React useState setter not working inside useEffect with axios

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

UseState setter inside promise.then() doesn'tUseState setter inside promise.then() doesn't work

This is my useEffect hook

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
      // axiosClient.get('user').then((data) => console.log(data.data.data.id));
      console.log(authAPI.isLoggedIn().then((res) => {
        setIsLoggedIn(res)
        console.log('done!', isLoggedIn)
      }));
    }, []);
```

This is my api:

```
async isLoggedIn() {
        try { 
            const res = await axiosClient.get('user');
            console.log(res.data.data)
            if (res.data.data.id) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch(err) {
            return false
        }
    },
```

and this my client:

```
get(apiUrl) {
      const response = axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: this.url + apiUrl,
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      return response
    },
```

When i use `.then((res) => res` on the promise I get the value that I want, which is "true" however when I try to set it with `setIsLoggedIn(res)`it doesn't work. It just stays with its default value which is false. I don't understand why it is happening.. I have the value and I set it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that console.log('done!', isLoggedIn) is logging the previous state value of isLoggedIn, which is still false, even after you have called setIsLoggedIn(res).

This is because setIsLoggedIn is asynchronous and does not immediately update the state. So when you log isLoggedIn immediately after calling setIsLoggedIn, it still shows the previous value.

To see the updated value of isLoggedIn, you can either use console.log('done!', res) instead of console.log('done!', isLoggedIn) or add isLoggedIn to the dependency array of your useEffect hook so that the hook runs again when isLoggedIn changes and logs the updated value.

Here's an updated version of your code with the dependency array added:

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  authAPI.isLoggedIn().then((res) => {
    setIsLoggedIn(res)
    console.log('done!', isLoggedIn)
  });
}, [isLoggedIn]);
```

Or you can log the updated value of isLoggedIn directly:

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  authAPI.isLoggedIn().then((res) => {
    setIsLoggedIn(res)
    console.log('done!', res)
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Be careful adding the `isLoggedIn` dependency here, though. Once the `setIsLoggedIn()` is called the first time, the `useEffect()` will rerun on that next rerender, which would call `authAPI.isLoggedIn()` and the `.then()` which calls `setIsLoggedIn()` again. At that point it will rerender again. This time the `useEffect()` shouldn't rerun because its dependency is still the same, but that's still an extra API call.